# Redirect all HTTPS requests to HTTP temporary in Apache on Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, https, ubuntu-16.04

My site was hosted in an hosted provider which had enabled certificates so the website in the google results is appearing with the `https://` in the beginning.

Since, yesterday I have setup my site in a VM (`Ubuntu Server 16.04` with Apache2) which currently don't have any enabled certificate for the domain. The `.conf` file is like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin  myemail@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Is possible to edit the `.conf`. Is it possible to redirect all the traffic from https to http?

Comment: I don't understand the reason of down-voting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a HTTPS `VirtualHost` to handle HTTPS requests and redirect them to HTTP. However, this VirtualHost would still need valid certificates to work correctly as the redirect happens after the SSL negotiation, so it's better consider creating new certificates using [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)  as it doesn't only provide increased security but improves search ranking.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know to install letsEncrypt due to an error  I get while I trying to install the certificate `Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA.`

Comment: That's another question, but you would need to look at the challenge you are using and configure your system to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not using SSL these days is not a good idea. Plus there is no way to make your clients not run into an invalid cert *before* they get redirected. You cannot avoid the browser warning this way at all.

You could use letsencrypt with `certbot-auto` to generate your own valid server certificates.

See here: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

It is really easy to install and use. The browsers will accept it as valid.